# Using select to pick out elements of nested lists in an odd way

Tags: list-manipulation, filtering

Suppose I have a nested list such as,

```
{{{A, B}, {A, D}}, {{C, D}, {A, A}, {H, A}}, {{A, H}}}
```

Where the elements of interest are,

> ```
> {{A, B}, {A, D}}
>
> {{C, D}, {A, A}, {H, A}}
>
> {{A, H}}
> ```

How would I use select to pick up only elements that contain two or more `A`s in the first part of their sub-elements.  In this example I would want the following as an output,

> ```
> {{A,B},{A,D}}
> ```

Comment: This does it: `Cases[{{{A, B}, {A, D}}, {{C, D}, {A, A}, {H, A}}, {{A, H}}}, {___, {A, _}, ___, {A, _}, ___}]`

Comment: Yep this is exactly what I am looking for.  Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
list = {{{a, b}, {a, d}}, {{c, d}, {a, a}, {h, a}}, {{a, h}}}

Pick[list, Count[#[[All, 1]], a] >= 2 & /@ list]
```

or

```
Select[list, Count[#[[All, 1]], a] >= 2 &]
```

or

```
Cases[list, _?(Count[#[[All, 1]], a] >= 2 &)]
```

or

```
DeleteCases[list, _?(! Count[#[[All, 1]], a] >= 2 &)]
```

all give

```
{{{a, b}, {a, d}}}
```

Comment: This is probably the best answer, since it uses the select command explicitly.  Thanks!

Comment: @kguler executing your `Select` with, f.e., `list = {{{a, b}, {c, a}}, {{c, d}, {a, a}, {h, a}}, {a, h}, {{a, b}, {a, c}}, {{a, b}, {q, r}, {a, d}}}` I get an error message and a result which is, the question being utterly ambigous, debatable.

Comment: @eldo, good observation re implicit assumption that is the source of the error message: although OP's example has that structure, it is not explicitly stated that  all sublists  have  depth >=2. However -- removing `{a,h}` or changing it to `{{a,h}}` -- I don't understand why the result is "debatable".

Comment: @kguler - This question has a short history of accepted and de-accepted answers and comments which were subsequently deleted. "Debatable" because the OP is unsure about what he really wants. Hopefully, your excellent answer stays awarded. (But a `Case`-solution would be more appropriate imo) :)

Comment: @eldo, I see. I missed the deleted comments. And I now see why the wording "elements that contain two or more As in the first part of their sub-elements" could be read differently from my reading of it -- of course, with the help of  desired output  -- as " two or more elements whose first part is equal to A"

Answer (score 2):

I chose a slightly different formulation:

```
expr = {{{A, B}, {A, D}}, {{C, D}, {A, A}, {H, A}}, {{A, H}}};

Select[expr, Count[#, {A, _}] > 1 &]
```

> ```
> {{{A, B}, {A, D}}}
> ```

I will note that this form is faster all four in the Accepted answer:

```
list = RandomChoice[CharacterRange["A", "H"], {500000, 3, 2}];

Select[list, Count[#, {"A", _}] > 1 &]                  // Timing // First

Pick[list, Count[#[[All, 1]], "A"] >= 2 & /@ list]      // Timing // First
Select[list, Count[#[[All, 1]], "A"] >= 2 &]            // Timing // First
Cases[list, _?(Count[#[[All, 1]], "A"] >= 2 &)]         // Timing // First
DeleteCases[list, _?(! Count[#[[All, 1]], "A"] >= 2 &)] // Timing // First
```

> 0.592804
>
> 0.795605
>   0.811205
>   0.936006
>   1.060807

Answer (score 2):

```
list = {{{A, B}, {A, D}}, {{C, D}, {A, A}, {H, A}}, {{A, H}}};
```

---

Using `Position` and `Extract`:

```
Extract[#, Position[#, m_?MatrixQ /; Count[m[[All, 1]], A] > 1]] &@list

(*{{{A, B}, {A, D}}}*)
```

Or using `Replace`:

```
Replace[list, m_?MatrixQ /; Count[m[[All, 1]], A] <= 1 :> Nothing, {1}]

(*{{{A, B}, {A, D}}}*)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
list = {{{a, b}, {a, d}}, {{c, d}, {a, a}, {h, a}}, {{a, h}}};

p = Position[list, x_ /; Count[First /@ x, a] <= 1, 1, Heads -> False]
```

{{2}, {3}}

```
Delete[p] @ list
```

{{{a, b}, {a, d}}}

```
MapAt[Nothing, p] @ list
```

{{{a, b}, {a, d}}}

Answer (score 1):

```
list = {{{A, B}, {A, D}}, {{C, D}, {A, A}, {H, A}}, {{A, H}}};

If[Count[First /@ #, A] >= 2, #, ## &[]] & /@ list
```

> {{{A, B}, {A, D}}}