# How to select sub-lists having at least one element that matches a pattern

Tags: list-manipulation, filtering

This will probably be a very easy question, yet although I did find a relatively [similar one](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/56082/using-select-to-pick-out-elements-of-nested-lists-in-an-odd-way), I couldn't use the answers there to solve my problem (I'm still a novice).
I'm simulating 10 blocks of pairs of dice tosses with

```
RandomChoice[Range[6], {10, 2}]
```

I would like to select those (and only those) sub-lists that contain at least one number greater than 4 (so I want {1,5} but not {4,4}, etc.). I tried both `Cases` and `Select`, but without any success.

For example, I was hoping this might work:

```
Select[RandomChoice[Range[6], {10, 2}, {___, # > 4 &, ___}]
```

But it doesn't. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You might be interested in [this thread](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/34861).

Comment: Yes, very impressive indeed. Many thanks!

Comment: There are [things to do after your question has been answered](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers). Its good to stay vigilant some time after you get the first answer as its likely that better approaches may come later improving over a previous reply and experienced users may point to caveats. Therefore, new users may **wait 24 hours** before [voting](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote) the deserving answers and [accepting](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) the best one for you. (Links contain useful information)

Comment: @rhermans: Thanks for the advice. I did vote all of the answers up, but that's because I checked each of them out, and they all solved the problem that motivated this post. I haven't noticed the accept feature, thanks for pointing that out as well. I also wasn't aware that one is not supposed to say "thank you" to someone who helps, so sorry for that. (Having read the guidelines, I can't help feeling that this comment itself is also inappropriate.)

Comment: Chatty comments are not encouraged, that is true, but we are all still humans. There is no need to apologize, I was just evangelizing "best practices" with a "prerecorded message" and you did nothing wrong.

Comment: The rational behind the policy is to avoid content that doesn't help future readers. So probably we could allow ourselves chatty comments provided they are deleted once they become obsolete. That's a topic for [meta].

Comment: Good point. In that case, this exchange is probably not for posterity:)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just to add a solution using [`ContainsAny`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ContainsAny.html) and [`Cases`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Cases.html)

**EDIT**: Updated in 10.3: [`MemberQ`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MemberQ.html) This is the clearest to read.

### Data

```
data = RandomInteger[{1, 6}, {16, 2}]
(* {{2, 6}, {1, 3}, {5, 2}, {1, 3}, {2, 4}, {3, 1}, {6, 2}, {4, 
  5}, {4, 4}, {5, 1}, {4, 4}, {4, 5}, {4, 2}, {2, 1}, {6, 3}, {5, 2}} *)

hugedata = RandomInteger[{1, 6}, {1000000, 2}];
```

### ContainsAny

```
Select[data, ContainsAny[{5, 6}]]
```

Or

```
Select[data, ContainsAny[#, {5, 6}] &]
(* {{2, 6}, {5, 2}, {6, 2}, {4, 5}, {5, 1}, {4, 5}, {6, 3}, {5, 2}} *)
```

Speed: Quite slow

```
First@Timing[Select[hugedata, ContainsAny[#, {5, 6}] &];]
(* 11.0761 *)
```

### MemberQ

[`MemberQ`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MemberQ.html), updated to operator form in *Mathematica 10.3*

```
Select[data, MemberQ[Alternatives @@ {5, 6}]]
(* {{2, 6}, {5, 2}, {6, 2}, {4, 5}, {5, 1}, {4, 5}, {6, 3}, {5, 2}} *)
```

Speed: Decent but not the fastest.

```
First@
 Timing[Select[hugedata, MemberQ[Alternatives @@ {5, 6}]];]
(* 1.93441 *)
```

### Cases

Using [`Cases`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Cases.html)

```
Cases[data, {_, 5} | {_, 6} | {5, _} | {6, _}]
```

Or equivalently but more general

```
Cases[data, Alternatives @@ Permutations[{_, (5 | 6)}, {2}]]
```

Speed: This one is fast!

```
First@
 Timing[Cases[hugedata, {_, 5} | {_, 6} | {5, _} | {6, _}];]
(* 0.421203 *)
```

**UPDATE**

Slower but "cleaner" using [`OrderlessPatternSequence`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/OrderlessPatternSequence.html)

```
Cases[data, {OrderlessPatternSequence[_, (5 | 6)]}]
```

Comment: Simple and elegant, especially the one using `Permutations`. Thanks!

Answer (score 11):

This is good for big list

```
l = RandomInteger[100, {1000000, 2}];

Timing[Pick[l, Times @@@ UnitStep[4 - l], 0];]
(*{0.546875, Null}*)
```

**Update**

For better timing also try this:

```
Timing[Pick[l, Min /@ UnitStep[4 - l], 0];] 
(*{0.046875, Null}*)
```

Comment: this is neat +1 :)

Answer (score 9):

One way to do this:

```
BlockRandom[SeedRandom[42, Method -> "MersenneTwister"]; (* for reproducibility *)
            p = RandomChoice[Range[6], {10, 2}];
            q = Select[p, Or @@ Thread[# > 4] &]];

p
   {{5, 1}, {1, 4}, {6, 6}, {4, 3}, {3, 4}, {2, 6}, {4, 3}, {5, 3},
    {2, 2}, {3, 1}}

q
   {{5, 1}, {6, 6}, {2, 6}, {5, 3}}
```

Comment: +1 for pointing out `BlockRandom`

Comment: @Bob, I do like using that function a lot; I often answer questions here during lulls in whatever I'm working on, and I quite like being able to seed the PRNG temporarily, without the seeding affecting the current PRNG state my other computations are depending on.

Answer (score 7):

```
SeedRandom[42, Method -> "MersenneTwister"];

p = RandomChoice[Range[6], {10, 2}]

(*  {{5, 1}, {1, 4}, {6, 6}, {4, 3}, {3, 4}, {2, 6}, {4, 3}, {5, 3}, {2, 
  2}, {3, 1}}  *)

Select[p, Max @@ # > 4 &]

(*  {{5, 1}, {6, 6}, {2, 6}, {5, 3}}  *)
```

As [J.M. is back](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/50/j-m-is-back) points out in his comment below, this can be written more concisely as

```
Select[p, Max@# > 4 &]

(*  {{5, 1}, {6, 6}, {2, 6}, {5, 3}}  *)
```

Comment: You could just do `Select[p, Max[#] > 4 &]`; then your answer will be officially nicer than mine. ;)

Answer (score 7):

```
func[lst_] := Pick[lst, Max /@ Sign[lst - 4], 1]
```

**Update with some timings**

Test functions:

```
algohi1[r_] := Pick[r, Times @@@ UnitStep[4 - r], 0];
u[r_] := Pick[r, Max /@ Sign[r - 4], 1];
algohi2[r_] := Pick[r, Min /@ UnitStep[4 - r], 0];
```

Using `RepeatedTiming` as informed to me by Silvia:

```
rc = RandomChoice[Range[6], {1000000, 2}];
RepeatedTiming[#[rc]][[1]] & /@ {algohi1, u, algohi2}
```

yielded: {0.84, 0.0731, 0.0767}

**Original answer**

This was just to play and using "distance"

```
df[x_, y_] := Min[Abs[x - y]]
    fun[x_] := Pick[x, df[#, {6, 6}] <=1 & /@ x]
    rc = RandomChoice[Range[6], {20, 10, 2}];
    col[x_] := Style[x, Red] /; df[x, {6, 6}] <= 1
    col[x_] := x
    Grid[Map[col /@ # &, rc]]
```

[image]

**Timings**
Using Mr.Wizard's `timeAvg`:

```
SetAttributes[timeAvg, HoldFirst]

timeAvg[func_] := 
 Do[If[# > 0.3, Return[#/5^i]] & @@ Timing@Do[func, {5^i}], {i, 0, 
   15}]
```

and inspired by Algohi's answer:

```
r = RandomChoice[Range[6], {1000000, 2}];
timeAvg[fun@r;]
timeAvg[Pick[r, Times @@@ UnitStep[4 - r], 0];]
timeAvg[Pick[r, Max /@ Sign[r - 4], 1];]
```

yield: 5.45313, 0.703125, 0.06 respectively.

Comment: There is a [`RepeatedTiming`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RepeatedTiming.html) in 10.1 now.

Comment: @Silvia thank you I did not know this...always learning something :)

Comment: Your method is pretty fast! (+1 already :)

Comment: @ubpdqn can you add the updated solution in my answer to your timing comparison. Thanks

Comment: @Algohi midnight here...will aim to do in am :)

Comment: @ubpdqn oh, just starting my day here. sweet dreams -:)

Answer (score 4):

Maybe this:

```
Select[RandomChoice[Range[6], {10, 2}], First[#] > 4 || Last[#] > 4 &]
```

Comment: I think this wins for me in terms of comprehensibility. Cheers!

Comment: Or replace "First[#] > 4 || Last[#] > 4 &" by "Max[#]>4&", which is a bit easier to read and interestingly  quite a bit faster (1.375 sec. rather than 2.125 sec. on hugedata as defined by rhemans).